# MVC3 localization for default validation errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, localization, data-annotations

When I put `[Required]` attribute on my ViewModel's property MVC3 automatically generate error messages like:
`The Price field is required.`

My site's single language is Russian, so I want to have localized error messages. I can localize field's name with `[Display(Name = "blablabla")]`, but how can I localize the `field is required` part?

Update:
I know, that I can change an error message for concrete field by specifying it `[Required(ErrorMessage = "blablabla")]`, is there a way I can change it in one place for all `[Required]` attributes, so I could use just `[Required]` without additional parameters, and it took the localized error message from some ressource/config/etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created an alternative solution where you don't have to use the attributes for the localization. I've created custom model/validation meta data providers.

All you need to do is to download my code and do the following in your global.asax:

```
var stringProvider = new ResourceStringProvider(Resources.LocalizedStrings.ResourceManager);
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new LocalizedModelMetadataProvider(stringProvider);
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new LocalizedModelValidatorProvider(stringProvider));
```

(the `ResourceStringProvider` is my default implementation but it's easy to create an alternative that reads from XML files or a database)

You can read about it here:
http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/easy-model-and-validation-localization-in-asp-net-mvc3/

I'm going to release a nuget package as soon as I'm finished with my view localization and my alternative HTML helpers.

Answer (score 1):

The Required attribute has properties that allow the message to be read from a resource string. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx for the details

Answer (score 1):

Granted for this you should already have some Resource Manager which can return localized texts for string keys. My `ResourceManager` has static accessor for this (and registrations with Unity for DI), so there's no need to pass it.
In the `global.asax`:

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new LocalizedModelMetadataProvider(); //field name localization
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new LocalizedModelValidatorProvider()); //validation message localization
```

And the implementation is this:

```
public class LocalizedModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType,
                                                    Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {

        var metadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);

        if (containerType == null || propertyName == null)
            return metadata;

        if (metadata.DisplayName == null)
            metadata.DisplayName = ResourceManager.Current.GetLocalizedAttribute(containerType, propertyName);

        if (metadata.Watermark == null)
            metadata.Watermark = ResourceManager.Current.GetLocalizedAttribute(containerType, propertyName, "Watermark");

        if (metadata.Description == null)
            metadata.Description = ResourceManager.Current.GetLocalizedAttribute(containerType, propertyName, "Description");

        if (metadata.NullDisplayText == null)
            metadata.NullDisplayText = ResourceManager.Current.GetLocalizedAttribute(containerType, propertyName, "NullDisplayText");

        if (metadata.ShortDisplayName == null)
            metadata.ShortDisplayName = ResourceManager.Current.GetLocalizedAttribute(containerType, propertyName, "ShortDisplayName");

        return metadata;
    }
}

public class LocalizedModelValidatorProvider : DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider
{
    protected override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
    {
        foreach (var attribute in attributes.OfType<ValidationAttribute>())
            attribute.ErrorMessage = ResourceManager.Current.GetValidationMessage(attribute);

        return base.GetValidators(metadata, context, attributes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply add/change the globalization tag in web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <globalization uiCulture="your culture"/>
```

Comment: Do you have installed framework language pack? "You may also want the localization files for things like the DatePicker and jQuery UI on NuGet via "install-package jQuery.UI.i18n." See here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx